# How do I sort mixed text&numbers (eg hostnames)?

Tags: sort

Given input with mixed text and numbers *(w/o leading zeros)*, how can I get it sorted in the "natural" order?  For example, given the following input (hostnames):

```
whatever-1.example.org
whatever-10.example.org
whatever-11.example.org
whatever-12.example.org
whatever-13.example.org
whatever-2.example.org
whatever-3.example.org
whatever-4.example.org
whatever-5.example.org
whatever-6.example.org
whatever-7.example.org
whatever-8.example.org
whatever-9.example.org
```

I would like this output:

```
whatever-1.example.org
whatever-2.example.org
whatever-3.example.org
whatever-4.example.org
whatever-5.example.org
whatever-6.example.org
whatever-7.example.org
whatever-8.example.org
whatever-9.example.org
whatever-10.example.org
whatever-11.example.org
whatever-12.example.org
whatever-13.example.org
```

### EDIT

I should have mentioned that in addition to the "whatever"s there would also be

```
thingaroo-#.example.org
      .
      :

blargh-#.example.org
      .
      :

...etc...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have GNU coreutils ≥ 7.0, then you can use version sort. This is lexicographic order except that sequences of digits are ordered according to their value as an integer in decimal notation.

```
sort -V
```

Comment: This appears to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2):

That particular style of input could be successfully be sorted with

```
sort -t - -nk2,2
```

but it doesn't really generalize to all sorts filenames, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Upvoted for being the only one to mention this is *not* a general solution.

Comment: This answer was very helpful in coming up with what I really wanted (see my question edit and answer).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I didn't give all the info needed in my original question.  All the answers were useful to me in coming up with what I really wanted.  What I ended up using was:

```
sort -t- -k1,1 -k2,2
```

where:

```
-t-       divide the hostnames into fields using dash (-) rather than spaces
-k1,1     the first sort key is the first field (from 1 to 1), a normal sort
-k2,2     the second key is the second field using a numeric (n) sort
          (the field includes the ".example.org" but the numeric sort
          seems to cope find with the trailing non-number chars)
```

this gives the result:

```
blargh-1.example.org
    :
blargh-13.example.org
thingaroo-1.example.org
    :
thingaroo-17.example.org
whatever-1.example.org
    :
whatever-13.example.org
```

Comment: Ah - good point :-o

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *whatever* in your text can vary, you need to use `sort` with the following options:

> -t, --field-separator=SEP use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
>
> k, --key=POS1[,POS2] start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2
>   (default end of line)
>
> -V, --version-sort natural sort of (version) numbers within text

```
sort -t "-" -k 2 -V < [filename]
```

Comment: This worked to sort them all by the numbers.  All the "1"s, then all the "2"s etc.  This was not what I wanted here, but still good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -t- -k2n file

whatever-1.example.org
whatever-2.example.org
whatever-3.example.org
whatever-4.example.org
whatever-5.example.org
whatever-6.example.org
whatever-7.example.org
whatever-8.example.org
whatever-9.example.org
whatever-10.example.org
whatever-11.example.org
whatever-12.example.org
whatever-13.example.org
```